# Letter "k" will not type on my form

Tags: html, forms, keyboard

I have no idea what this problem is, so I am not sure what piece of code to paste. I have my form looking perfect in safari firefox and chrome, at all media checkpoints. I can type the whole alphabet upper case and lowercase, all numbers, all symbols, EXCEPT for "K" and "k".

I am ready to publish my site, except I can't make it live with an issue like this. Is there anything I can try?

I can type in "K" and "k", it is not my keyboard, if it was I could not type it on this site.

Comment: What happens when keying a 'k' - does anything appear at all?
Are you using a custom font face?

Comment: Can you type the K in another sites? Maybe your keyboard is not working :)

Comment: You either can't see it (because of font), it is removed right after input (with JavaScript on event keyup/down) or does not work (keyboard failure).

Comment: seems like a keyboard issue...try it on another site like @Babblo said and make sure that everything works and tell us

Comment: @Markasofsoftware thanks for your reply, I apologize for not adding any code samples. Here is the tutorial I followed, so mine looks very similar. http://portfoliojs.com/

While using google chromes inspect element, I added a form to this live page, and it seems that typing the letter 'K' won't work on their page either. 

By deleting stuff on the page to break it down, it seems my form works fine when I delete either: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> or: step#4 in the tutorial, but then that also deletes my portfolio images.So it's gotta be in those files.

Comment: Could you be having some browser plugin installed, that claims the k-key as some kind of quick-key / short-cut ?

Comment: @nl-x that can't be the issue, as he said jquery is causing it

Comment: @NicolasFredrickson could you try my answer, it seems that in your situation it would likely fix it as jQuery is probably somehow cancelling the keypress

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure what the issue is with this random issue you have not provided even an example for, but, using JavaScript, this SHOULD stop any script that might possibly be `preventDefault`-ing letters:

```
function undoCancel(elt){
    function cancelUtil(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    elt.addEventListener('keydown',cancelUtil,true);
    elt.addEventListener('keypress',cancelUtil,true);
    elt.addEventListener('keyup',cancelUtil,true);
    elt.addEventListener('input',cancelUtil,true);
}
```

and then call that function for every element that the issue is occuring on (like this: `undoCancel(document.getElementById('somerandomid'))`. Also make sure that your keyboard's `k` key isn't broken, that seems to me like the most likely issue. Don't change the `true` in `addEventListener` to `false` either, with `true` it will catch stuff before most events are fired.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'enableKeyboardNavigation' option to false--this is the code you placed in your file, the part with the settings.

This resolves the problem anyone would have with any keyboard input related to portfoliojs.com

:-)

Comment: can you also suggest WHY using enableKeyboardNavigation to false solves it? And how do you know This resolves the problem anyone would have with any keyboard input